# Cumulative distribution of $Y=\max(0,-X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

Let $X$ be a random variable having continuous cumulative distribution function $F(x)$.  What is the cumulative distribution function of $Y = \max(0, -X)$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$
F_Y(y)
 = \mathbb{P}[Y \le y]
 = \mathbb{P}[\max\{0,-X\} \le y]
$$

When is $\max\{a,b\} \le y$? When both $a \le y$ and $b \le y$...

Comment: So your saying $P_{Y}(y) = 0$ for $y<0$ and $1-F(-y)$ for $y>0$  can we generalize this?  How can we use it to find $F_{Y}(y)$